# Gitlab - NoMethodError (undefined method `tag_names' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby, git, ubuntu, gitlab

After doing a fresh install on my server, and successfully creating a new project from the front end, i'm trying to push to repository and i fail consistently. After some debugging i found the following in the production.log. I can see that the repository folder is empty no matter what. Nothing is created in there. I've checked my Nginx configuration and it seems fine, no extra slashes or anything. I'm really lost.

```
   NoMethodError (undefined method `tag_names' for nil:NilClass):
  /home/git/gitlab/app/models/repository.rb:105:in `block in tag_names'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/cache.rb:296:in `block in fetch'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/cache.rb:587:in `block in save_block_result_to_cache'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/cache.rb:548:in `instrument'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/cache.rb:586:in `save_block_result_to_cache'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/cache.rb:296:in `fetch'
  /home/git/gitlab/app/models/repository.rb:104:in `tag_names'
  /home/git/gitlab/lib/gitlab/git_access.rb:56:in `push_allowed?'
  /home/git/gitlab/lib/gitlab/git_access.rb:27:in `allowed?'
  /home/git/gitlab/lib/api/internal.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Internal>'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/grape-0.6.1/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:31:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/grape-0.6.1/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:31:in `block in generate_api_method'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/grape-0.6.1/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:401:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/grape-0.6.1/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:401:in `run'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/grape-0.6.1/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:154:in `block in call!'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/grape-0.6.1/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:24:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/grape-0.6.1/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:24:in `call!'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/grape-0.6.1/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:18:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/grape-0.6.1/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:24:in `call!'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/grape-0.6.1/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:18:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/grape-0.6.1/lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:26:in `block in call!'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/grape-0.6.1/lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:25:in `catch'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/grape-0.6.1/lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:25:in `call!'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/grape-0.6.1/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:18:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:138:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/grape-0.6.1/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:155:in `call!'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/grape-0.6.1/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:145:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:68:in `optimized_each'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/grape-0.6.1/lib/grape/api.rb:525:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/grape-0.6.1/lib/grape/api.rb:42:in `call!'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/grape-0.6.1/lib/grape/api.rb:38:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/request_store-1.0.5/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-cors-0.2.9/lib/rack/cors.rb:54:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-attack-2.3.0/lib/rack/attack.rb:63:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:138:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:65:in `block in call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `each'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `call'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:552:in `process_client'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-worker-killer-0.4.2/lib/unicorn/worker_killer.rb:51:in `process_client'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:632:in `worker_loop'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:500:in `spawn_missing_workers'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:142:in `start'
  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `load'
  /usr/local/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `<main>'
```

My SSH settings are fine, the Gitlab installation is good and i've tried every single thing i found on the web. Any ideas? I know some users are still dealing with similar issues. Any workarounds? Here are some log outputs.

```
Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 1.9.7 ? ... OK (1.9.7)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
Satellites access is drwxr-x---? ... yes
update hook up-to-date? ... yes
update hooks in repos are links: ... 
1/17 ... repository is empty
1/18 ... repository is empty
Running /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: OK
Check directories and files: 
/home/git/repositories/: OK
/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys: OK
Test redis-cli executable: redis-cli 2.2.12
Send ping to redis server: PONG
gitlab-shell self-check successful

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes
Number of Sidekiq processes ... 1

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking LDAP ...

LDAP is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking LDAP ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
Database contains orphaned UsersGroups? ... no
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... yes
projects have namespace: ... 
1/17 ... yes
1/18 ... yes
Projects have satellites? ... 
1/17 ... can't create, repository is empty
1/18 ... can't create, repository is empty
Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes
Ruby version >= 2.0.0 ? ... yes (2.1.2)
Your git bin path is "/usr/local/bin/git"
Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (2.0.0)

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

and my setup:

```
System information
System:     Ubuntu 12.04
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  no
Ruby Version:   2.1.2p95
Gem Version:    2.2.2
Bundler Version:1.7.2
Rake Version:   10.3.2
Sidekiq Version:2.17.0

GitLab information
Version:    7.2.1
Revision:   ff1633f
Directory:  /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter: postgresql
URL:        http://git.mySite.com
HTTP Clone URL: http://git.mySite.com/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@git.mySite.com:some-project.git
Using LDAP: no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:    1.9.7
Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:      /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:        /usr/local/bin/git
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it would not make you happy but this seems to be an unresolved bug related to Ruby version.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/281